# open folder with one click

Tags: macos, finder, folders

Is it possible to open folders with just one click in Mac OS 10.11? Renaming could be done using context menu with right click then.

Comment: What view are you using? If you use finder and the 3 window view (the button next to the 4 dashlines) you can navigate without clicking twice.

Comment: I want to open icons. E.g. folders displayed on Desktop.

Comment: @rwzdoorn, There is no such view in Finder as "3 window view", it's called Columns view or in context of your comment it's the Columns view button and make note that not all Finder windows display the Toolbar so the View buttons may not be present on some Finder windows.

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to open folder with one click in default "Icons" view in Finder. However switching to "Columns" view (cmd-3) will allow you to open folder with one click.

Also it could be faster to just use hotkeys instead of trackpad/mouse. Use arrows to navigate inside "Icons" view, cmd-down to open selected folder and enter to rename selected file or folder. When no file or folder is selected, you could just type in file/folder name and Finder will select closest match for you.

Comment: Ok. But I prefer navigating with mouse.

Comment: @marsch This answer still addresses that preference