# How to open a folder in Finder by a single mouse click? (using Icon view)

Tags: finder, desktop

Is there a setting, key combination or similar to open a folder/subfolder in Finder with a single mouse click ?  I need a general solution which works on any folder in effort to minimize needless clicking ... that tiny triangle aside the folder icon will work yet its just too small and only appears using list view ... inspired by same behavior on osx inside a browser to hold down command key and single click a web link ... forcing users to double click is so 20th Century

Is there a way to enable this on macOS (High Sierra or higher)?

On ubuntu this single click preference is a simple setting ;-)

Comment: view the folder in list view, click once on the disclosure triangle to the left of the folder you want to open, voilá.

Comment: "a keyboard combo... in effort to minimize needless clicking": click the folder, followed by cmd+O = 1 click and a keyboard combo ;)

Comment: Comments should be used to clarify issues with the post they belong to. For general discussions chat is more appropriate.

Comment: @nohillside A reply, or edit would clarify the question.  I'm assuming (maybe wrongly) that the author of the question is looking for a different solution, but didn't clearly state so.  Hence my jestingly suggested answer in the comment, which should satisfy the question as it stands, but most likely is not what the poster expects.

Comment: @Redarm My comment above was related to some off-topic comments which I deleted in the meantime. Understand your idea, but assume that the OP is looking for "a setting or a key combination to enable one-click folder opening in general" :-)

Comment: Yes, the old "View as Buttons" option in Finder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [open folder with one click](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245933/open-folder-with-one-click)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you on double click.  I bought a multi-key mouse.  I assign a key to double click. Not a perfect or free solution, but better.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible natively in macOS

While you may be able to assign a double click mouse action or a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>) to your mouse but using something like AppleScript (i.e [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/133232/double-click-in-applescript?rq=1) and [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/266784/119271)) or [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) there is one main obstacle that must be overcome - the lack of *hover to select*.

However, there is an App called [DwellClick](https://pilotmoon.com/dwellclick/) which is designed to automate your mouse clicking for you.  They have a feature called "point to click" which will select an item if you leave your pointer on it for a specified amount of time.   After which you can click with a reassigned mouse button to emulate double click.